# what is the syntax for oracle pl sql function overloading?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, overloading

I'm trying to perform function overloading in oracle live plsql. There is no basic syntax which works for function overloading anywhere that I could find.

using 1 parameter

```
create or replace function area(a in number)
return number is
begin
    return a*a;
end;
```

using 2 parameter

```
create or replace function area(a in number, b in number)
return number is
begin
    return a*b;
end;
```

Functions get created once executed. But, gets error during function call.

```
declare
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(area(5));
    dbms_output.put_line(area(3, 4));
end;
```

Help me with the error and construct this code into basic syntax for function overloading.

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 31:
> PLS-00363: expression '5' cannot be used as an assignment target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-47D5A50E-7AAF-4C80-A06A-37593EA2526A) says:

> PL/SQL lets you overload nested subprograms, package subprograms, and type methods

Nothing about *standalone* stored procedures (functions).

Therefore, if you put those functions into a package, it works as expected:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    function area (a in number) return number;
  3    function area (a in number, b in number) return number;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    function area(a in number)
  3    return number is
  4    begin
  5        return a*a;
  6    end;
  7    function area(a in number, b in number)
  8    return number is
  9    begin
 10        return a*b;
 11    end;
 12  end;
 13  /

Package body created.

SQL> begin
  2      dbms_output.put_line(pkg_test.area(3, 4));
  3      dbms_output.put_line(pkg_test.area(5));
  4  end;
  5  /
12
25

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot. I tried the same in packages and it worked but, is there some way to make it work in individually without packages.???

Comment: You're welcome. There's none, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Littlefoot, which editor you are using for PL/SQL code? It looks nice !

Comment: I can understand :-)

Comment: @Soumendra: That's what I do when there's not that much code and when I don't have TOAD (which is whenever I'm not at work). TOAD's Formatter does its job well and nicely formats code. GUI I use at home is SQL Developer, but I don't like the way it formats code. Sometimes - when someone posts a lot of unformatted code - I use some of online SQL formatters (don't have any favorite; just Google for it when necessary).

Comment: I've never known any PL/SQL formatter work the way I like, so it's generally a two-step process - use the formatter (after carefully reviewing every possible setting), then clean up after it. Or if it's my own code, I just type it neatly to start with :)

Answer (score 2):

```
set serveroutput on
declare
   function area(a in number,
                 b in number default null)
     return number is
   begin
   
      if b is null then
         return a*a;
      end if;
   
      return a*b;
   
   end area;
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(area(5));
   dbms_output.put_line(area(3, 4));
end;
```

HTH.